# Unable to find the cause for java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to run the below program,

```
public class Ocerloading {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] month_days = new int[12];
        String[] month_name = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
                "October", "November", "December" };

         for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {

            if (i == 1) {
                month_days[i] = 28;
                continue ;
            }

            if (i <= 6) {
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                    month_days[i] = 31;

                else
                    month_days[i] = 30;
            } else {
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                    month_days[i] = 30;

                else
                    month_days[i] = 31;
            }
        }

        for (int x : month_days) {
            System.out.println(month_days[x]); 

        } 


    }

}
```

It is giving the below error,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 31
    at Ocerloading.main(Ocerloading.java:32)
```

I understand that this error occurs when we try accessing an array element that is out of range. But this does not seem to be valid.

I edited the output.

Comment: Eran's answer is correct. You could have discovered this quite easily by using a debugger to step through your code and example the value of `x` prior to the exception. Using a debugger is a key skill for a programmer, not something to think about learning later. As soon as you've managed to write code that compiles, it's time to start learning how to step through that code with a debugger.

Comment: @Stewart, as mentioned, it mentions EnhancedForLoop and hence most likely the line `for (int x : month_days) { ...`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think `month_days` is an `int[]` for storing the indices. That clearly is the intent, if you read the code ...

Comment: @Sid I think the exception happens on the line `month_days[i] = 31;`

Comment: @Stewart: No, if you read the code, `month_days` is clearly an array containing the number of days in a given month, e.g., `month_days[0]` is `31` for January.

Comment: @Stewart, not really, it occurs in the enhanced for loop because the code treats it as indices, while they are actual values.

Comment: OK, I see my mistake now ...

Comment: Those who are downvoting the main OP's question because it seems too rudimentary, please don't.  People have to begin somewhere, and we at SO are there to support them.  The OP has provided clear code and the question is also to the point. He is a beginner, let's help him out and not discourage to ask questions on here.  Thanks.

Comment: Er, I meant "...and *examine* the value of `x`...", not "...and *example* the value of `x`..." which makes no sense at all. :-)

Comment: @kiran, if you find any answer satisfactory, please accept it. Helps improve SO.

Comment: @Sid Thanks for encouraging new learners like me. Eran's answer was helpful. I'm unable to upvote an answer yet.

Comment: @kiran, You can see a tick mar below each answer.  You can click it to mark it as valid answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood the enhanced for loop. It iterates over the elements of the array, not their indices.

It should be :

```
for (int x : month_days) {
    System.out.println(x); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [enhanced `for` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html), introduced in Java 5, gives you the elements of the array. You are expecting it to give indexes like a conventional `for` loop.

e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < month_days.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(month_days[i]); 
}
```

Above will work because we are taking indices.

In your case, make the following change:

```
for (int x : month_days) {
    System.out.println(x); 
}
```

This is because here `x` is not the array index, but rather `x` is the actual value stored in `month_days` array.  So when it tries to find `month_days[12]`, it fails, because `month_days` has size 12 and hence 0-11 indices.

Comment: Holly molly sugar lolly, is this answer incorrect?  Downvoters please also add some feedback.  Helps me and SO improve.  Danke.

Comment: Please make an effort to find duplicates before you post an answer. I literally wrote `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException foreach` in search and found the linked post above. We don't need hundreds of copies of the same question.

Comment: Agreed, will follow it.  Thanks for the comment.